# Has anyone tried the AKG ULS series

Tags: field-recording, microphone, self-noise

I'd love to hear some opinions on, or recordings made with these. The specs look good, especially that 9 to 11dB-A self noise across the range of capsules. I'm thinking these could make a good multipurpose XY pair for recording both ambiance and fx.

[From the AKG site.](http://www.akg.com/ULS+Series-791.html?pid=1386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They look interesting, I haven't used them and I can't find any good reviews. 
But it seems like they are targeted/marketed to live sound technicians.
And in regards to their 'ultra linear' claim, AKG don't offer any information in the form of frequency responses. I've read one post on gearslutz about the fact that AKG don't offer matched pairs either and that tolerances (mva and f response) are way off in this case.

It seems like the only way to test them is renting and buying..